# Ember app served from express urls don't work after refresh

Tags: express, ember.js, routes

In ember I build for production into the `/client` folder in my express app. In express at the bottom just before I start the app I have these lines

```
var api = require('./app/routes/api');

app.use('/api/v'+apiVersion, api);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

That works up until I refresh the page at which point it returns a `Cannot GET` for that route, in my logs from `morgan` in the terminal I see it's making a call to `/url_here` instead of routing to the index.html file and allowing ember to take over from there. Do I need to set this up a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your express app need to handle 404 error and send 'index.html' of client app.

Add this code at the very bottom (below all others):

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/client/assets'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
```